Modifying the tree via org-element API
I have an Org mode document. My goal is to create a new Org document with modified contents of the original (some nodes removed, different level of indentation, etc). I'm using the org-element API.
I managed to use org-element-parse-buffer to get the source tree, and create a whole new (valid) tree after doing some processing. Now I want to take this new tree and add the property "BLAH" with value "Yadda" to all nodes - right before I export to an org file using org-element-interpret-data.
Here is my attempt:
(defun test ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((tree (my-make-tree)))
    (org-element-map tree 'headline
      (lambda (node)
    (org-element-set-element node (org-element-put-property node :BLAH "Yadda"))
    ))
    (princ (org-element-interpret-data tree))))

It seems it didn't modify tree. It runs the function, but it seems org-element-set-element returns a new node, but doesn't insert it into the tree.
I can't find any relevant function in the org-element API to do this. I suppose I could create a buffer, insert the tree as a proper Org doc, and modify it then, but I really prefer modifying it prior to "export".

There are different kinds of properties at play here and org-element-put-property does not deal with the same kind of properties that org-entry-put (e.g.) deals with: the first basically annotates an AST node with some information; the second add a property into the properties drawer of a node. I think you'd be better off working against the buffer, rather than against the AST. See Using the Property API and Using the Mapping API in the Hacking appendix of the Org manual.

BTW, your code does add the property :BLAH with the value "Yadda" to every node. If you look at the tree in memory, you'll see them. But as explained in the previous comment, these are not the properties that you are looking for...

Assuming what is in memory is a string, rather than a different type of data structure, it is possible to walk along the string and modify it, although of course seeing it in a buffer is easier to visualize and compose programmatic modifications.  Here is a link to a thread where I was stubbornly persistent in my refusal to use a buffer to make modifications to the string in memory:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/24343/2287

@lawlist no, the AST is not a string: it's a complicated data structure. It's only at the org-element-interpret-data step that the AST is serialized into a string.

@NickD,
I don't want to use org-entry-put, as that modifies the buffer, and I want to modify the tree.
When I manipulate the tree, it doesn't exist in any buffer. I could put it in a buffer as a string and use org-entry-put, but that is slow. As an example, I can very quickly modify the ID of each node in the AST using org-id-uuid - almost instant. It takes much, much longer doing it using org-id-get-create.
And at least in my org mode (9.5.5), my code above is not modifying the tree. It is returning new nodes with the property set - not putting them in the tree.

It seems I was misunderstanding how org-element APIs work. Someone elsewhere pointed out I need to traverse the tree and build a new tree with the modified nodes. I'll give that a try.
There are 3 levels of modification: 1. Modifying the entry in the actual buffer (which you can do with org-element-map. 2. Modifying the tree. 3. Modifying the node (but not the tree). I wish the docstrings were clearer which of these apply for each function. It also took me time to understand that "contents" is "children", etc.
If I had time, I'd improve the Worg article.
